# How to mantain state of sealed class variant inside ViewModel which depends on a MutableStateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I have a piece of UI which depends on the value of a sealed class. Depending on the type of the sealed class, this UI element has different forms. Also, each variant of the sealed class contains variables that affect the UI and should be modifible and mantained across screen rotations. Here is a piece of code that shows what I'm trying to do:

```kotlin
class TestViewModel : ViewModel() {
    enum class TestEnum { Test1, Test2 }
    private val _choose = MutableStateFlow(TestEnum.Test1)
    val choose = _choose.asStateFlow()

    sealed class TestSealed {
        class Test1(n : Int) : TestSealed() {
            val n = MutableStateFlow(n)
        }
        class Test2(s : String) : TestSealed() {
            val s = MutableStateFlow(s)
        }
    }
    
    val test = choose.map {
        when(it) {
            TestEnum.Test1 -> TestSealed.Test1(0)
            TestEnum.Test2 -> TestSealed.Test2("asd")
        }
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), TestSealed.Test1(0))

    fun toggle() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _choose.update {
                when(it) {
                    TestEnum.Test1 -> TestEnum.Test2
                    TestEnum.Test2 -> TestEnum.Test1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun TestPreview() {
    AppTheme(true) {
        Surface(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            val vm = viewModel<TestViewModel>()
            Column {
                Button(onClick = { vm.toggle() }) {
                    Text("toggle")
                }
                val test by vm.test.collectAsState()
                when (val t = test) {
                    is TestViewModel.TestSealed.Test1 -> {
                        val n by t.n.collectAsState()
                        Button(onClick = { t.n.update { n + 1 } }) {
                            Text("increment")
                        }
                        Text("Test1 $n")
                    }
                    is TestViewModel.TestSealed.Test2 -> {
                        val s by t.s.collectAsState()
                        Button(onClick = { t.s.update { "foo" } }) {
                            Text("foo")
                        }
                        Text("Test2 $s")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code almost works: the problem is that when I rotate the screen, the current value of the variable `test` is lost, and I would like to mantain it. But it makes no sense for me to store both `n` and `s` inside the `ViewModel`, because they are used only when `choose` takes one of the values.
I know the problem is that the `MutableStateFlow` in `SealedTest` is not stored inside a ViewModel, but I have no idea how else to be able to update and subscribe to `s` and `n`. Fundamentally, the problem is that the variable that decides what UI is drawn (`test`) also contains data that should be store and saved, but decoupling said data from `test` means storing data that is potentially useless because the UI is not using it.
How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "I know the problem is that the MutableStateFlow in SealedTest is not stored inside a ViewModel" This is false. The ViewModel instance is kept in memory when you rotate the screen. You may be having some issues due to `Test1` and `Test2` not having proper `equals` and `hashcode` functions that actually take their state into account. --- However, even though the state flow is kept in memory when the screen rotates, you still will want to restore the state in the event of the task being cleared from memory and getting restored when the app is resumed. That will require....

Comment: ...translating your state to/from a saved instance state Bundle in your ViewModel (put that in its constructor and inherit from AndroidViewModel), or storing and restoring from disk.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm not sure I follow. You're saying that if I implement `equals` and `hascode` for `Test1` and `Test2`, the state will be correctly saved inside the ViewModel as the screen rotates, without changing anything else about the code (ignoring for the moment the problem of the state not being saved as the app is cleared from memory)?

Comment: No, I’m just suggesting the first step towards making your code make sense, but I don’t know your exact issue. It’s also weird that you have a StateFlow of classes whose “value” is another StateFlow. I haven’t reasoned out the logic of that, but I’ve never tried it and intuitively it feels very wrong.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I basically have a dropdown menu, and depending on the item selected, a different UI element appears. I need to keep track of the UI state between screen rotations, but it feels stupid to store every possible UI element that could appear beforehand. Therefore, I decided to put every possible UI element in a sealed class, and every variant contains the info that it needs to keep track of when it is on screen. It seems quite a basic scenario to me, and it doesn't feel right to be forced to store useless information that the UI is not using.

Comment: That’s fine, but the sealed classes shouldn’t have flows in them.  I thought it through further. If you change the value in the nested flow, the top level flow cannot detect that a change has happened because it’s still referencing the same instance. It’s completely nonviable. Make the sealed class’s children into data classes that wrap data directly with no flow in them and see how it behaves then.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 bits of info to save.  The test choice, and the values in the test classes (one string, one int).  What is the lifetime of the test classes and for that matter the view model?

Update:
remember can be used with within a composable to ensure a value is saved through recomposition, but as tenfour04 stated, is not applicable to viewModel.

`val n = remember { MutableStateFlow(0) }`

But, you could just as easily have this as a member of the viewModel directly.

There's a codelab dealing with compose, viewmodels, and covers rotation
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#9

Post: tenfour04 brings up a very good point that it's always good to look at the source for things.  I never use viewModel with remember, as imports were missing from example code, hard to be sure what viewModel actually is doing in the construction or retrieval.  Anyway, seems the compose viewModel is what's used: import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel, in build.gradle, implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1'

Still, the basic principles apply of thinking about scope/lifetime management.  Proceeding methodically through each aspect of code is a sure way to find out what's not working to resolve it.

Comment: Not true. You don't have to remember the returned ViewModel. See the documentation of the `viewModel()` function. It already behaves as if it is remembered. This is because it is being retrieved from the Activity or Fragment's ViewModelStore. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/package-summary#viewModel(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner,kotlin.String,androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory,androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.CreationExtras) Notice even in the codelab you linked, they don't wrap `viewModel()` in `remember`.